# After send an email page is not redirecting in magento2

Tags: magento2, email, email-templates

After email sent page is not redirecting. Email function is using in magento2 helper.

```
$transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateConfigId)
                    ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
                    ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                    ->setFrom([
                        'name' => $fname,
                        'email' => $femail,
                    ])
                    ->addTo($email)
                    ->getTransport();
            //echo get_class($transport);
            $transport->sendMessage();
```

Email is coming but page is not redirecting. can anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: after send email you can redirect specific page like this :- **return $this->redirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');**

Comment: Not working. it display the blank page. @RkRathod

Comment: please upload your code

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :-**

```
protected $redirectFactory;

public function __construct(\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\RedirectFactory $redirectFactory)
{
   $this->redirectFactory = $redirectFactory;     
 }

public function yourFunction()
{

 $transport = $this->_transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier($templateConfigId)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => $storeId])
                ->setTemplateVars($emailTemplateVariables)
                ->setFrom([
                    'name' => $fname,
                    'email' => $femail,
                ])
                ->addTo($email)
                ->getTransport();
        //echo get_class($transport);
        $transport->sendMessage();

        $result = $this->redirectFactory->create();
        return $result->setPath('*/*/');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. but, it not redirecting from helper.

Comment: which path you want to redirect??

Comment: i need to redirect current page

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Not working still blank page only